# Dart - Whats equivalent of C# Stream/MemoryStream and stream.WriteByte(..) for Dart

Tags: flutter, dart-pub, dart, uint8list

Need to achieve following in `dart`

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(288);
stream.WriteByte((byte) 13);
stream.WriteByte((byte) 12);
stream.WriteByte((byte) 10);
stream.WriteByte((byte) 8);
stream.WriteByte((byte) 6);
stream.WriteByte((byte) 9);
var result = stream.ToArray();
```

I am coming from C#/java background and trying to use `Uint8List` which is equivalent to `byte[]` and also more efficient than `List<int>`. While I can `add` `int8` in `Uint8List` but `Uint8List` can only be initialized with fixed-length. I need something dynamic where I can just say `write` or `add` without the need of any index to add. No idea how `add()` of `Uint8List` works. Couldn't find much on the internet or in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a standard equivalent. (There's [a GitHub comment explaining why `Uint8List` requires a fixed length](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/15014#issuecomment-108403211).)

You instead could:

- Use `List<int>` and convert to a `Uint8List` afterward.
- Create your own class that wraps a `Uint8List`.  When extra capacity is needed, you would need to allocate a new `Uint8List` that has, say, double the previous size, and to copy the old elements. (This is what most other growable list implementations (e.g. C++'s `std::vector`) do.) Possibly there is some existing Dart package on pub.dev that already does this.
- Make a class that wraps a `List<Uint8List>`, adding new `Uint8List` members as capacity is need and concatenating them into a single `Uint8List` when done.  There is a third-party [`buffer` package](https://pub.dev/packages/buffer) that can do this, but I have never personally used it and can't vouch for it.

Comment: Is there anything similar to Outputstream or stream to write data as we go?

Comment: @Rohit I don't know what `Outputstream` is.  If you're looking for something that can do efficient concatenation (like C++'s `std::stringstream`), I think the closest equivalent from the Dart SDK would be `StringBuffer`.  There is a third-party [`buffer` package](https://pub.dev/packages/buffer) that does the same thing for byte data.

Comment: "Buffer package" looks promising, will give it a try. May be the thing I am looking for! Thanks

Comment: I forgot to note that I've never used and can't vouch for the `buffer` package; it was just the first result when I searched for "buffer" on pub.dev.

Comment: Never popped that result for me, may be I was searching different terms like "streams".

Comment: Can you edit your answer with buffer package as a solution. `buffer` package has `ByteDataWriter` which does exactly what I mentioned in the code example in the question. @jamesdlin

Comment: @Rohit Okay, done. (The other approaches I mentioned could do exactly what you mentioned in your code example too. ;) )

Answer (score 0):

[Uint8Buffer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/typed_data.typed_buffers/Uint8Buffer-class.html) is similar to MemoryStream

`add()` is like `WriteByte()`, and you can pass `Uint8List` to `addAll()` so it's like `Write()`

Note https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/typed_data.typed_buffers/typed_data.typed_buffers-library.html

> These lists works just as a typed-data list, except that they are
> growable. They use an underlying buffer, and when that buffer becomes
> too small, it is replaced by a new buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Use [BytesBuilder](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-io/BytesBuilder-class.html) from `dart:io`.